# In react-native whats the best way to upgrade the project

Tags: react-native

Present in my project I am using react-native version 0.56.0. I want to upgrade my project to latest 0.61, and I had used nearly 60 third-party modules, what's the best way to upgrade my project to the latest version of react-native. can anyone suggest me how can I do it in a better way, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced in this problem and I have upgraded lots of project so my suggestion is that you should create a new project using react-native init yourOldProjectName then add all the dependencies using yarn or npm. Then follow the all third party libraries document one by one and build the project probably you will get 3-4 or more issue then fix them but I haven't found any other best way to upgrade the react-native project.

Comment: i had created new project and integrated all the third party libraries, but already my app is in playstore, which keystore file should i keep in new project to update my app in play store.

Comment: please user old keystore file.

Comment: I placed 'my-release-key.keystore' from my old in new project android/app. is it enough or anything should I do?

Comment: You will have to follow https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

Comment: Setting up Gradle variables document

Comment: so I should create new upload key and use the old release-key.keystore in my project

Comment: No just just follow the document and use the old keystore file and just change the file name my-release-key to my-upload-key.keystore

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use the update helper tool provided by the react-native-community. Here is the link:

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.56.0&to=0.61.2